# Python Package Download in offline environment :( ('typing_extensions-4.0.1')

Tags: python, django, setup.py, offline-mode

I'm trying to run a Django Application in an offline internal network environment.
I have a problem in the process of downloading requirements for this.

Currently, I'm installing Python packages using the 'setup.py install' command.
However, there is no setup.py file in the 'typing_extensions-4.0.1' package, so it's impossible to download the package. I want to ask for advice on how to solve it.

For your information, 'conda', 'pip' conmmands are not available.

Answer (score 1):

In case you weren't aware, it is possible to use pip in an offline install too.

```
pip install --no-deps --no-index some-package.whl
```

you'll of course need to download the .whl file in some manner first, e.g.:

```
pip wheel --wheel-dir /tmp some-package==1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Welcome to Stackoverflow,

this might be a little of the wall, looking at the repo `https://github.com/python/typing/`,

1. clone the repo to your computer `git clone git@github.com:python/typing.git`
2. take, `src/typing_extensions.py and copy it into your project
3. import and see if it works.

If you run into issues let me know and have a play around